# ActionScript Crash Course

Tags: actionscript-3

I was just asked to revamp all of the training which uses action script. Anyone have a good recommendation for a book or site that will provide a decent crash course with Adobe Action Script?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a good Actionscript 3.0 book for experienced developers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600276/what-is-a-good-actionscript-3-0-book-for-experienced-developers)

Comment: fair point, but that question was asked and answered in 2009.

Comment: the colin moock book was released in 2007, which is considered the AS3 bible.  by the way, it wasn't me who down voted your question, though i did vote to close it on the count of it being a possible duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[http://www.amazon.com/Essential-ActionScript-3-0-Colin-Moock/dp/0596526946/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596526946)

I recommend that book.

Comment: +1 definitely check this one out, its the best there is. There is also a DVD tutorial series (by the same author) that covers a lot of this content as well, you may want too look at that, though I haven't check it out myself. Its here: http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596801526

Comment: also check out Keith Peters' ActionScript 3.0 Animation http://goo.gl/P5Gfd and Advanced ActionScript 3.0 Animation http://goo.gl/XBdzk books after you read Moock.  they're lots of fun and the logic/algorithms are portable to other languages.